# In a general eigenvector with eigenvalue having a multiplicity of 2, why is the first entry substituted instead of the other two for this example?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My question is about the computation of the eigenvector that corresponds to an eigenvalue with a multiplicity higher than 1. This is a pretty long example that establishes my question.

The matrix problem I am referring to can be seen in this link.

https://matrixcalc.org/en/vectors.html#diagonalize%28%7B%7B4,-2,-2%7D,%7B-2,4,-2%7D,%7B-2,-2,4%7D%7D%29

In determining the eigenvectors of the following matrix,

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    4 & -2 & -2 \\
    -2 & 4 & -2 \\
    -2 & -2 & 4 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

The characteristic equation is
$$ -\lambda^3 + 12\lambda^2 -36\lambda = 0  $$

Solving for the eigenvalues,
$$ \lambda = 0 \ and\ 6 $$

The eigenvalue of 6 has a multiplicity of 2.

Substituting it to matrix $$ A - \lambda I $$ makes the matrix

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    -2 & -2 & -2 \\
    -2 & -2 & -2 \\
    -2 & -2 & -2 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Which can then be reduced to row-echelon form

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Where the equation
$$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0 $$

Can be transformed into
$$ x_1 = -x_2 + -x_3 $$

Which makes the eigenvector
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1  \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}

Equal to
\begin{pmatrix}
-x_2 -x_3 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}

My question is, why was the first variable expressed in terms of the second and third variable? I got this problem right up until that step. Honestly, I don't have a good grasp of solving eigenvalues that have a multiplicity higher than one.

Do you always pick the first variable as the one being substituted? Why does it not work that way for other problems where you can choose what variable to express the eigenvector in? Does it have to do with the roots being 0 and 6 where 6 has a multiplicity of 2, which is why the first entry is substituted? What if the eigenvalue of a order 3 matrix had 2 distinct values but the lesser value had the multiplicity of 2? Would things change? What would also happen if it was an order 4 matrix with two distinct values each having a multiplicity of 2? Would both matrices have the first and second entries in the eigenvector be substituted?

Can people refer me to any reference regarding solution of eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues with multiplicity higher than 1? Honestly I tried searching but most that I have seen are so complicated. I mean call me stupid if I can't find them and they are easy to find, but I really couldn't get much of what I have seen. Most of them focus on the multiplicity part and not the eigenvectors.

This all leads to the bigger picture of, how do you solve for eigenvectors in general. I think I have a good grasp of solving because it was just really the substitution that I messed up in. More knowledge regarding this topic would help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For $\lambda=6$ with multiplicity 2 the eigenvector $(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$ would satisfy $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$. Next choose two sets of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ such that the two eigenvectors $X_1, X_2$ are orthogonal: $X_1^T X_1=0$
So we get $X_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\-2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $X_2=\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: In my solution of the eigenvector, I only managed to get X_2 and not X_1. I guess your solution might have a basis but the topic is not something I am familiar with. Why does X_1 not come up as an eigenvector of the matrix I mentioned above when using the characteristic polynomial? I am just asking, not invalidating since I am only familiar with that method of solution and would probably need more explanation.

Comment: When an eigenvector has multiplicity 2, ypu will get a unique relation for $x_1,x_2,x_3$. In order to get two linearly independent ev you can choose them to be non-parallel (making, any angle other than 0 and $\pi$) vectors.  If they are orthogonal it is better.